# Custom Basic TextField Design when used with singleLine Boolean distort paddings

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

While working on a custom text field in jetpack compose, I ended up with a weird scenario where if I put singleLine Boolean to true, the contentPadding is completely ignored by compose.

```
@Composable
fun CustomTextField2(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    placeholder: String,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions(),
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape =
        MaterialTheme.shapes.small.copy(bottomEnd = ZeroCornerSize, bottomStart = ZeroCornerSize),
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.42f),
        cursorColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.7f)
    )
) {
    val textColor = textStyle.color.takeOrElse {
        colors.textColor(enabled).value
    }
    val mergedTextStyle = textStyle.merge(TextStyle(color = textColor))

    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
    (BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        modifier = modifier
            .background(colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value, shape)
            .indicatorLine(enabled, isError, interactionSource, colors)
            .defaultMinSize(
                minWidth = TextFieldDefaults.MinWidth,
                minHeight = TextFieldDefaults.MinHeight
            ),
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        enabled = enabled,
        readOnly = readOnly,
        textStyle = mergedTextStyle,
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(colors.cursorColor(isError).value),
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = value,
                visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
                innerTextField = innerTextField,
                singleLine = singleLine,
                enabled = enabled,
                placeholder = { Text(text = placeholder) },
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                colors = colors,
**                contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 30.dp),
**            )
        }
    ))
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewCustomTextField2() {
    var name by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    CustomTextField2(
        value = name,
        onValueChange = {
            name = it
        },
        placeholder = stringResource(id = R.string.name))
}
```

[image: preview]

When preview, it exactly as I am desired but when i put the singleLine boolean to true, this is how it ends up
[image: after setting boolean to true]

when I did a little research I found the the culprit,
[image: singleLine Devil]
As mentioned in the comment of the image, if its a singleLine, the label's start position is in the center of the container. When it's a multiline text field, the label's start position is at the top with padding. So, my question is how do I use my custom padding on textfield with singleLine set to true?

Comment: Use ```BasicTextField``` and remove extra padding and customize as your choice. Reference https://gist.github.com/chiragthummar/1d028533711be9b3b698e7cc1fe8c831

Comment: I am actually using basicTextField. I want all of TextField properties but not the contentPadding, so i have just changed the contentPadding to 30.dp from top. So, it align text over the indicator line properly as i intended. But as soon as i set the boolean of singleLIne to true, the text align itself to the centre and completely ignoring the padding value I gave.

Comment: Use ```maxLines=1``` instead of ```SingleLine```

Comment: of course i did that.